# What is the proper way of nesting related CSS lines?

Tags: css, nested

I am trying to nest these lines of code together, I have tried the following but it does not work, is there any other way to have both the button and a tag changed by hovering the button through a single piece of code ?

```
  .about-right button:hover {
  background: #91c8ff;
  & .a {
    color: #151515;
  }
}
```

Here is the orginal code:

```
.about-right button:hover {
  background: #91c8ff;
}

.about-right button:hover a {
  color: #151515;
}
```

Comment: *through a single piece of code* --> not with pure CSS

Comment: Looks like you want to use SCSS features in a CSS file